# sails.js no userId when a route is called by browser

Tags: javascript, session, sails.js, session-cookies

I have some asset (js file) that I create dynamically in a sails app (according to the user), in order to do so I created an action and bound it to a route.

when I call this route directly, everything works as expected. but when I try to load it in an HTML file with  tag, it seems it doesn't recognize me as logged in.

how can I get the user to be recognized that way?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is lacking in key details and I don't really think anyone can help you without seeing the code. Please provide either a minimal, reproducible example (e.g. reproduce the problem in a new project and post it on github) or show some well-documented code focused around the flow of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the issue:

I logged in through localhost that created a session for this host, while loading the script in my html with 127.0.0.1, so it didn't use the session created for localhost.

once I changed my html to load with the script with localhost, I get recognized.